# How to execute a method after completion of three processes in .net

Tags: c#, .net, process

I am running three same processes by using Process.start and by passing different arguments.I need a logic in way like only after completion of these proccess i have to execute last two methods named   `fourthmethod();sendmail();`.How to do this.The existing logic is throwing these two method all the time,but i need only after the completion of three proccess ie three methods  `firstmethod();`, `secondmethod();`, `thirdmethod();`
This code shows triggering three different process

```
 // three same test.exe process
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    Process.Start("test.exe",i);
    }
```

In test.exe main method

```
Main(strin[] args)
{
if(args[0]==0)
{
firstmethod();
}
if(args[0]==1)
{
secondmethod();
}
if(args[0]==2)
{
thirdmethod();
}
fourthmethod();
sendmail();
}
```

Comment: Use OnExit Event.  See following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
  static int count = 0;
  static object obj = new object();
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Process[] Processes = new Process[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Processes[i] = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
        Processes[i].EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Processes[i].Exited += Program_Exited;
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
  }

  private static void Program_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
    lock (obj)
    {
        count++;
    }
    if (count == 3)
        Console.WriteLine("Finised");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> One Way to do it :)
>
> Updated Code :

```
 // three same test.exe process
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)   // the two method should execute only after 3 processes
    {
    Process.Start("test.exe",i);
    }
```

> Updated code Test.exe

```
Main(strin[] args)
{
if(args[0]==0)
{
firstmethod();
}
if(args[0]==1)
{
secondmethod();
}
if(args[0]==2)
{
thirdmethod();
}
if(args[0]==3)    // i shall increment to 3 only if the first three processes are ran 
{ 
fourthmethod();
sendmail();
 } 
}
```